# Is it possible to get a unique device id for device i am using in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, device, uuid

I am currently using nodejs as backend and I would like to get a unique device id for each device that access my website. Is there any npm package that do that. I tried node-machine-id but it gave me the same device id when i sumbitted the request through my phone and laptop which are two different devices yet i got the same Id any help

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Node.js really.  Simply generate a random ID and save it in a long-lived cookie.

Comment: Ok i just wanted to make sure is there an npm package that could detect device id without storing it in a cookie

Comment: There is no inherent device ID.  You'll have to create one specific to your application and store it somewhere, such as a cookie or local storage.

Comment: Ok thank you for you help 

Comment: May be check xforwarded it gives you ip for particular request then you can generate random uuid as per the ip

Comment: Quick question is it possile to use mac address as device identifier

Comment: For web based app its all public IP provided by ISP ,you cant get mac address unless the client and server are on same network